# ¿modificar archivos pdf con PHP?

Tags: php, pdf

Tengo la necesidad de adjuntar un pdf en uno solo cierta cantidad (el mismo pdf).

ejemplo si el usuario eligió 5.

Entonces hacer cinco copias de ese mismo pdf adjuntas en un solo documento.

por ejemplo el pdf que eligió solo tenia una hoja, en el resultado final debería haber 5 copias de ese archivo adjuntas en un solo pdf. Aparte de eso también necesito modificar el pdf agregar la siguiente información ya sea en la parte superior o inferior.

ejemplo. como son 5 hojas en total: entonces en cada hoja agregar algo como fecha y numero de hoja: **DIA/MES/AÑO HH:MM p. numeroDeHoja-TotalHojas.**

cada hoja de ese pdf tendría la siguiente información respectivamente.

```
(16/11/2021 10:11 am 1-5)
(16/11/2021 10:11 am 2-5) 
(16/11/2021 10:11 am 3-5) 
(16/11/2021 10:11 am 4-5) 
(16/11/2021 10:11 am 5-5)
```

no sé si me hago entender. que librería pdf podría usar para ese fin con PHP, gracias.

Comment: Modificar un PDF no es una opción buena, todo lo contrario, debes crear tu info y después de que tengas todos los parámetros de usuario, allí justo creas tu PDF con lo que necesitas

Comment: Las preguntas que buscan ayuda con la depuración deben incluir el comportamiento esperado, un problema específico o error, y el código más corto necesario para reproducirlo en la propia pregunta. Las preguntas sin un planteamiento claro del problema no son útiles para otros lectores. Véase: Como crear un [mre]

Comment: es que estos documentos ya están guardados, entonces tengo esa necesidad, cada que el usuario desee descargar x_pdf

Comment: @Excorpion por eso plantee el problema, si no conozco como manejar documentos pdf con php entonces que otra información debería agregar?, también agregue un ejemplo de que información debería ir en el resultado final.

Comment: Lo primero es lo primero, como crear un PDF.

Comment: @Excorpion pero el tema no es crearlo es modificarlo, los pdf ya estan realizados.

Comment: Puedes crear el pdf con esta clase ``R&OS PDF PHP Class``, pero si lo que quieres es modificar un pdf ya creado, ahí desconozco como hacerlo.

Comment: @rpaillao gracias por responder, seguiré investigando cómo dije en el problema la necesidad es modificarlo.

Comment: Las modificaciones se hacen con las mismas herramientas con las que creas uno. Por eso primero es aprender eso... hablamos de librerias de PDF para php. Como dije... lo primero es como crear un PDF.

Comment: @Excorpion vale gracias por responder, seguiré investigando.